# Weighted NMF custom objective function for NMF package in R

Tags: r, matrix-factorization

It seems [`NMF` R package (v0.22)](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/NMF/index.html) does not yet allow out-of-the-box weighted non-negative matrix factorization (WNMF), but welcomes a custom algorithm ([p.25 here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/NMF/vignettes/NMF-vignette.pdf)). I'm trying it out, but not sure if I'm on the right track. Has anyone implemented custom algorithms for `nmf()` already? Any sketch-examples that can get me started with WNMF? 
Consider:

```
set.seed(0)
X=runif(10) %*% t(runif(5))
X[missing <- X<.05] = 0
W = 1*(!missing)
```

WNMF ignores zero values of `X` (mapped via zeros of `W`) and approximates `X` by element-wise multiplying both sides by a weight matrix `W` as in `W.X ~ W.BL`, i.e. by minimizing a Frobenius (or some other) norm `|W.X - W.BL|`.

UPDATE1:
Created objective function, but can't figure out how to pass `W` to it. I'm  guessing that `method` argument now needs to take a custom algorithm, but online examples are scarce. Ideas are welcome.

```
WNMF_ObjFn = function(model, target, W, ...) {
  sum(W*(target - fitted(model))^2, na.rm=T) 
}

library(nmf)
res = nmf(X, rank=2, objective=WNMF_ObjFn, W=W)

Error in fun(y, x, ...) : 
  unused argument (W = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1))
Timing stopped at: 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I overlooked an easy solution. `ls-nmf` algorithm is basically a weighted NMF and is already implemented by `nmf` R package.

```
nmf(X, rank=2, method="ls-nmf", weight=W)
```

Still, I'd value anyone's solution to the earlier exercise of creating a custom objective function, which (I think) requires a custom algorithm to go along with it.